# using multiple conditions in iam policy

Tags: conditional-statements, identity-management

I am trying to give two conditions StringEquals and ArnEquals. The StringEquals block is working whereas ArnEquals block is failing. Even after i gave the correct federated user of mine. I am unable to start build. here is what i am trying. I am getting the error the user with xxxx arn is not allowed to stratbuild action.

```
- Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - codebuild:StartBuild
              - codebuild:StopBuild
              - codeBuild:RetryBuild
            Resource:
              - !Sub arn:aws:codebuild:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:project/*
            Condition:
              StringEquals:
                aws:ResourceTag/Application:
                  - yyy
                  - xxx
                aws:ResourceTag/TargetEnvironmentType:
                  - dev
              ArnEquals:
                aws:SourceArn: 
                  - !Sub arn:aws:sts::${AWS::AccountId}:federated-user/Builder-role/xxx@gmial.com
```